# Regular Expression-Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Please help!  I'm stuck.

How do I solve this problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Write a program that indicates the single greatest integer in the text /users/abyron/resources/urantia.txt

Comment: Share the text file

Comment: I am sorry, there is no text file.  It has to be done on linux server through nano.

Comment: can you atleast share a sample of what i am dealting with here (words, numbers, special characters?) so that i can make a regex expression to filter it out.

Comment: btw, you can dowload the file from the server with `wget url/of/file`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for helping.  I made a typo.  The text is /users/abrick/resources/urantia.txt   So I've opened the file, and it includes integers.